# SQL Sum by and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I am having an issue using the SUM function of MySQL.

I have a table with a 'code', 'year', 'scenario', 'month' and 'value' variables. The 'value' column is decimal (11,3) type.
The idea is to SUM values by code.

When I select the SUM by code by Quarter I use the following code (for Quarter 1 -> Jan+Feb+Mar):

```
SELECT code, sum(value)
FROM volume
WHERE year=2016 AND scenario = 'Budget' AND month = 'JAN' OR month = 'FEB' OR month = 'MAR'
GROUP BY code, value
ORDER BY code Desc
```

NOTE: From this query I get the right result and I'm pretty happy.

.

Then I try to select the Full Year SUM by code.

When I try to build this query I use the following:

```
SELECT code, sum(value)
FROM volume
WHERE year = 2016 AND scenario = 'Budget'
GROUP BY code, value
ORDER BY code Desc
```

For this query the result I have is this:

```
V.9236 | 1962.950

V.9236 | 187.050

V.9230 | 2282.500

V.9230 | 217.500
```

When I should have:

```
V.9236 | 2150

V.9230 | 2500
```

Can you help me figure what's is wrong with the query?

Thank you all.

Comment: You don't need to group by 'value'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have to group by value, just code should be fine like:

```
 SELECT code, sum(value) 
 FROM volume WHERE year=2016 
  AND scenario='Budget' 
 GROUP BY code 
 ORDER BY code Desc
```